# How to animate a Scrolling horizontally in a div with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this code that adds buttons to scroll horizontally in a div and it is made by Vlad Danila but the problem is I can't animate the scrolling it just snaps. I tried to add a transition to the container but it didn't work.

```js
const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

buttonRight.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
};
buttonLeft.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 20;
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 145px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#content {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Click the buttons to slide horizontally!</div>
</div>
<button id="slideLeft" type="button">Slide left</button>
<button id="slideRight" type="button">Slide right</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to `#container`.

```js
const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

buttonRight.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
};
buttonLeft.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 20;
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 145px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#content {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Click the buttons to slide horizontally!</div>
</div>
<button id="slideLeft" type="button">Slide left</button>
<button id="slideRight" type="button">Slide right</button>
```